# B2B Commerce Lightning Custom vs Standard components

Tags: b2b-commerce, b2b, b2b-lex

I seek advice on what would be the best approach to take and if anybody maintains custom components which are almost copies of standard components.

I'm working on the shop where Search Product Results and Product Details were implemented as custom components (there are more but let's narrow the scope).
All looks good, works as expected, some API's are called in the background to get the product search results that customers are able to see as per configurations, looks complex but it's fine.

Now let's say we want to tackle promotions, no surprise at least from the developers perspective that the only thing related to promotions is on Cart Total which is a standard component.

Now I need to find a way to show promotions on custom components, I assume there will be some API that will handle all the configuration checks which customers apply for which discounts, calculate the price etc. (but not clear yet if that's available).

But from my perspective maintaining these custom components would look like rewriting the standard for each release. I would rather refuse any custom solutions like that and stick to standards, since building custom components for promotions, product searches and product details that are based on lots of configuration dependent factors (product visibility, discount qualifiers, discount calculations, buyer group product availability), can introduce a lot of complexity, at least from my perspective that I'm starting to work with B2B commerce.

I would like to hear others opinions:

- Should the above components like product search results, product details and promotions never be implemented as custom?
- Did anybody implement and agree to maintain such custom components in the future?

**Use Modular Components on the Product Detail Page**: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_b2b_comm_lex_modular_pdp.htm&type=5&release=234
Maybe components will get more modular in the future so that we are not left with either rewriting standard when some custom is needed or stick to standard but be limited to changes.

Comment: There aren't many B2B LEX users/devs out there in the wild atm, so I recommend joining this Trailblazer group if you haven't already (and ask your question there as well): https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000HWXUSA4?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my team has a suite of custom components - we use almost none of the standard components, and there are a few big reasons why:

1. We are in the process of integrating with Salesforce from a legacy system.  Salesforce is not yet the system of record for a lot of our data.
2. Our design requirements (which were dictated by a third party we hired prior to getting involved with B2B LEX) could not be met at all by what was available OOTB.
3. Our business logic - including pricing and product units of measure - are extremely complex and meant that using built-in cart and pricebook functionality would be a no-go either
4. Login requirements, both for internal and external users, also needed to have special consideration and implementations

We had no choice but to roll our own solutions for a lot of functionality.  If the components available OOTB can be used to meet your business requirements, and if you're fine with the look-and-feel of these components, I would say it's almost certainly a lot easier to maintain than introducing new features manually each release.  But, again, if it doesn't meet business requirements, custom components are, for better or for worse, pretty necessary.  Standard components don't give you much wiggle room.